# Is there any way to copy contents of one intent to another intent?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I want to copy all the content from one intent to another intent i.e;In my agent I want to use same Responses and Training phrases in different intents,How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no direct way to do this, however you can still achieve this using following method.

- Make a new agent which will have intent which you want to make copy of
- change the name of intent to whatever you want
- Select the intent and click on `copy`
- Select your original agent where you want to make copy of your intent

[image: copy 1]

[image: copy 2]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to do this with a large set of data, I would recommend using the new Knowledge connector features and storing your Q&A's outside of dialogflow.

Answer (score 0):

The best way that I've found is to export the entire agent as a zip file under the settings Export/Import tab.

Then, inside that zip file will be intents exported as JSON. Uncompress this.

You can then "copy" over the intents you wish to the other intents by making a copy of the JSON file, replacing the parentID and rootParentID with the parent you want to copy it to, while also generating a new id.

Then zip it back up, and import it.